# How to modify files in post-build script depending on a menuconfig flag?

Tags: authentication, buildroot, post-build

I need to find a way to modify/edit a given file after **Buildroot** compilation and right before the creation of the rootfs depending on a *menuconfig* flag selection. I could find in the **Buildroot** documentation that it is possible to do that by using *post-build* scripts.

My problem is that I would do the script action only if I selected something in *menuconfig*, for example:

```
(x) Enable my_login_system;
```

If I select *my_login_system*, then I need to change the *nsswitch.conf* file according:

```
passwd:        my_login files
```

If I don't select in menuconfig the "my_login_system", then the nsswitch.conf should be:

```
passwd:        files my_login
```

So, my main question is how to know if the "my_login_system" was selected or not in the post-build script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a post-build scripts is executed, it can access the `BR2_CONFIG` environment variable, which holds the path to the Buildroot `.config` file. Your script can parse that file and act accordingly.

Thus you could have a condition like:

```
if grep -q ^BR2_MY_LOGIN_SYSTEM=y ${BR2_CONFIG}
then
    # do some tweaks
else
    # do other tweaks
fi
```

Alternatively, you could use the `BR2_ROOTFS_POST_SCRIPT_ARGS` configuration variable to pass arbitrary command line parameters (as opposed to environment variables) to the post-build scripts.

Both possibilities are documented in the Buildroot manual, at section [Customizing the generated target filesystem](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#rootfs-custom).